# Refining linq query

Tags: performance, linq

Is there a better way to code this, without repeating access to the original list?

```
var list = new List<string> { "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7" };

if (list.Any(a => a.TYPE_CD == "F1")
    && list.Any(a => a.TYPE_CD == "F2")
    && list.Any(a => a.TYPE_CD == "F3")
    && list.Any(a => a.TYPE_CD == "F4")
    && list.Any(a => a.TYPE_CD == "F5")
    && list.Any(a => a.TYPE_CD == "F6")
    && list.Any(a => a.TYPE_CD == "F7"))
{
   return "All";
}
```

Comment: How does a member of `list` have a `TYPE_CD` field?

Comment: @NetMage, probably it's a custom class, not strings in that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the combination of `All` and `Contains` extension methods:

```
var temp=new HashSet<string> { "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7" };
var result=list.All(e=> temp.Contains(e.TYPE_CD))?"All":"Not All";
```

Comment: I would suggest using a `HashSet` for `temp`.

Comment: Right, great suggestion in case OP has big list to compare, thanks